# Como gerar uma lista com dados de um Checkbox Android?

Tags: java, android, lista, checkbox

Estou desenvolvendo um app Android para pizzaria que gera uma lista de ingredientes a partir de CheckBox assinalados, ou seja, o usuário dá um "check" nos itens que deseja para sua pizza como catupiry, calabresa, cebola, etc, e assim é montada a lista.

Minha dúvida é, como faço para que ao marcar um CheckBox, seu valor seja inserido na lista e, caso desmarque, o mesmo registro seja removido. Segue o trecho correspondente desse código:

```
    CheckBox cbOp1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbop1);
    CheckBox cbOp2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbop2);

    final ListView lvOp12 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvop12);

    final List<String> alPedido = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cbOp1.isChecked()) {
        alPedido.add(cbOp1.getText().toString());
    } else if (alPedido.contains(cbOp1.getText().toString())) {
        alPedido.remove(cbOp1.getText().toString());
    }

    if (cbOp2.isChecked()) {
        alPedido.add(cbOp2.getText().toString());
    } else if (alPedido.contains(cbOp2.getText().toString())) {
        alPedido.remove(cbOp2.getText().toString());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alPedido);

    lvOp12.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Gostaria de saber se essa de fato é a melhor solução? Tenho diversos itens que o usuário pode marcar e creio que meu código ficará muito extenso e inelegível dessa forma.

Comment: Creio que este post pode lhe ajudar http://techlovejump.com/android-listview-with-checkbox/

Comment: Olá Clever. Mto bom esse post, refiz as minhas listas utilizando esse artigo. Obrigado !